# Do we need a "boruta-tag"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

Boruta is a feature-selection algorithm based on randomForest. In my opinion we should have a tag for this algorithm.

Currently there are [23 questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20boruta) related to boruta.

What do you think?

Comment: That seems reasonable on its face. I don't know much about it, how distinctive is it? Can questions about boruta be grouped under an existing tag?

Comment: Well they could be grouped under the randomForest tag or under some kind of feature selection, but in my opinion it is a very specific type of feature selection just like PCA is a specific type of dimensionality reducation.

Comment: It seems reasonable for me. The tags are for making navigating on the site easier, it may serve the purpose.

Comment: Yeah, RF isn't specific enough. Would having `[random-forest]` & `[feature-selection]` be OK? If not, we should have the tag. There seems to be adequate demand for it. If you do create the tag, be sure to create an excerpt to guide its usage.

Comment: Okay I decided to create a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created the [boruta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/boruta/info) tag. Feel free to propose a more detailled wiki as I just have superficial knowledge of the algorithm.

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for having a look at it.